# Flatten each action from the Facebook API into its own column using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

The Facebook API response combines all actions into a single field, which is usually inconvenient for reporting. I would like to flatten each action into its own column as shown in the picture below.

[image]

```
"data": [
      {
        "actions": [             
          {
            "action_type": "comment",
            "value": "3"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "like",
            "value": "33"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "link_click",
            "value": "1531"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "mobile_app_install",
            "value": "1049"
          }
        ],
        "spend": "8621.03",
        "date_start": "2017-10-28",
        "date_stop": "2017-11-26"
      }
    ]

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
var values = data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]));
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

//Current Result from the existing Code - Console Log

["actions", "spend", "date_start", "date_stop"]
[[[{
  action_type: "comment",
  value: "3"
}, {
  action_type: "like",
  value: "33"
}, {
  action_type: "link_click",
  value: "1531"
}, {
  action_type: "mobile_app_install",
  value: "1049"
}], "8621.03", "2017-10-28", "2017-11-26"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data you get back from the Facebook API has a fixed structure, i.e. the number of actions is always the same.

```
function myFunction() {
 var data = [
  {
    "actions": [             
      {
        "action_type": "comment",
        "value": "3"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "like",
        "value": "33"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "link_click",
        "value": "1531"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "mobile_app_install",
        "value": "1049"
      }
    ],
    "spend": "8621.03",
    "date_start": "2017-10-28",
    "date_stop": "2017-11-26"
  }
]

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//flatten the objects
var actionObjects = data.map(returnAction)

//get the headers
var headers = Object.keys(actionObjects[0])

//create a 2D array for rows
var actionRows = actionObjects.map(a => headers.map(h => a[h])) 

//write the headers
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, headers[0].length).setValues([headers]);

//write the rows
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, actionRows.length, actionRows[0].length).setValues(actionRows);
}

function returnAction(data){
  let action = {}
  data.actions.forEach(a => action[a.action_type] = a.value)
  action ['spend'] = data.spend
  action ['date_start'] = data.date_start
  action ['date_stop'] = data.date_stop
  return action
}
```

Comment: What if actions are not a fixed structure. Will the code change

Comment: How can I make this dynamic? The fixed code works perfectly fine at my end

Comment: I suggest you take a large sample of the Facebook API data and find out if there is any difference in action types for each record. To cater for the dynamic action types, the code will need to change and will be more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the action list is quite long. However, users can select what actions type they want. For instance, mobile app install is one action type. So I want to make it dynamic based on user selection

Comment: The reason I said it would be complicated is that you have one row with an action like app install, but the other rows do not have that. You then need to combine all the actions from the flattened objects and work out the full list of actions as the headers. When setting the values for the cells, you will need to set null for rows that has no such header.

Comment: The code will work fine if you don't have the case I described above.